# How to find median of a list using indexing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to define a function, median, that consumes a list of numbers and returns the median number from the list. If the list is empty, then I want to return None. To calculate the median, I need to find the middle index of the list after it has been sorted. Do not use a built-in function. 
SURVEY_RESULTS = [1.5, 1, 2, 1.5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]

```
def median(SURVEY_RESULTS):
    length = 0
    order = sorted(SURVEY_RESULTS)
```

I'm not sure how to use indexing to now determine the median.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation：

```py
def QuickSort(myList,start,end):
    if start < end:
        i,j = start,end
        base = myList[i]

        while i < j:
            while (i < j) and (myList[j] >= base):
                j = j - 1

            myList[i] = myList[j]

            while (i < j) and (myList[i] <= base):
                i = i + 1
            myList[j] = myList[i]
        myList[i] = base

        QuickSort(myList, start, i - 1)
        QuickSort(myList, j + 1, end)
    return myList

def median(l):
    half = len(l) // 2
    return (l[half] + l[~half])/2 # Use reverse index

SURVEY_RESULTS = [1.5, 1, 2, 1.5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]

# Sort first
QuickSort(SURVEY_RESULTS, 0, len(SURVEY_RESULTS)-1)

result = median(SURVEY_RESULTS)

print (result)
```

Comment: I cannot use the builtin functions, i.e. len

Comment: Then you can count the number of element in this list in advance.
`for i in SURVEY_RESULTS:
    length = length + 1`
And replay every `len()` with `length`